# Handling double-variable switch statement with macro in C

Tags: c, macros, switch-statement

Let's say I have two pointers to two structs `a` and `b`. These two structs each contain an enum, which we'll call `x`. Given any possible `a` and `b`, I want to call a specific function based on the values of their `x` enums.
What is interesting in my case is that the functions that I want to call look like:

```
X0_to_X1();
X0_to_X2();
...
X1_to_X0();
...
etc
```

where `X0`, `X1` etc are possible values of the enum `x`, meaning that there are `X_to_Y` functions for every and each combination of the values of the `x` enum.

The obvious "naive" solution to this would be a switch statement which would be quite big (given that `x` has quite a few possible values):

```c
switch (a->x) {
    case X0:
        switch (b->x) {
            case X1:
                X0_to_X1();
                break;

// ... and so on and so forth for every possible pair!
```

My first attempt at solving this a bit more elegantly was to implement a macro that, given two values of `x`, could form a function call:

```c
#define CALL_FUNCTION(x1, x2) x1 ## _to_ ## x2 ()
```

This however does not work, as in my code I never can know the *actual* values of `x` before runtime, so it ends up looking like:

```c
CALL_FUNCTION(a->x, b->x);
```

which of course gets converted to:

```c
a->x_to_b->x();
```

which makes absolutely no sense.

Is there a way to solve this problem more elegantly, or should I just bite the bullet and implement the enormous switch statement instead?

Comment: What ranges are the values of `a->x` and `b->x`? If it's small enough you could create some kind of lookup-table that translates `a->x` and `b->x` into a function pointer that you could use.

Comment: `a bit more elegantly` you should rather write `a bit less readable and maintainable way`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I guess I can try that out... for the moment being there's only 7 possible values, however if I create, say, a static array to use as a lookup table I will need to be careful when adding new enum values (or explicitly associate the values with integers in the enum) so as not to change the indices of the LUT

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland how is needing to revisit a huge, nested switch statement each time I want to add a new enum _more_ readable/maintainable?

Comment: You could probably generate your huge switch from a list of the values using some variation on the theme of either X macros (and if the enums are yours, you can use a single list to generate those as well), or using something like Boost Preprocessor (e.g. `BOOST_PP_LIST_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT `).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem screams for a lookup table, where you store pointers to the various functions and they are keyed by the enumeration values.

If your `enum` values are sequential (and no two enumeration constants share the same value), then you can build a lookup table as a simple 2D array:

```
enum x_t { X0, X1, X2, ..., NUM_X }; 
void (*lookup[NUM_X][NUM_X])(void) = {
  { NULL, X0_to_X1, X0_to_X2, X0_to_X3, ... },
  { X1_to_X0, NULL, X1_to_X2, X1_to_X3, ... },
  { X2_to_X0, X2_to_X1, NULL, X2_to_X3, ... },
  ...
};
```

That assumes you don’t have an "identity” function when your `x` and `y` are the same.

Then, you call the desired function by indexing into to table like so:

```
if ( x != y )
  lookup[x][y]();
```

No, it isn’t pretty, but it beats nested `switch` statements.  You can hide that behind a macro or another function call if you wish.

If your enumeration values aren’t sequential then this particular implementation won’t work - you’d have to build your lookup table a different way, using lists or sparse matrices.  But while the setup code may be tedious, it will greatly simplify the logic on the calling side.